# Principal in EJB injected from REST service

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have a simple REST webservice that uses **basic authentication**.

```
@Path("/ws")
@Stateless
public class MyWebservice {
    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEjb;

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MyObject getObject() {
        return myEjb.getObject();
    }
}
```

The EJB is also really simple:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {
    @Resource(lookup = "java:comp/EJBContext")
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @PermitAll
    public MyObject getObject() {
        return new MyObject();
    }
}
```

However, when I debug, the principal in the EJB in the `sessionContext` is always "anonymous", no matter what user I use to authenticate against the WS.

How can I set the EJB principal to the same as the one that is authenticated against the webservice?

Comment: Which java ee version?

Comment: JEE7, the one provided by Wildfly 8

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
@Resource
EJBContext context;

...

context.getCallerPrincipal()
```